# Form opens but crashes after an Action finishes

Tags: c#, winforms, action

Let's say I have two forms. After using an Action called PantallaEspera, which creates a waiting screen, I want to open a new form, but it opens it and then crashes.

If I remove the Action, it works great. This is what I have done:

The loading screen:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RedBeetle.Forms_bueno
{
    public partial class PantallaEspera : Form
    {
        public Action Proceso { get; set; }

        public PantallaEspera(Action proceso)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Proceso = proceso;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Proceso).ContinueWith(t => { this.Close(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

The code where I call the action:

```
private void EjecutarBusqueda()
        {
            var listaUsuarios = AccesoDatos.DevolverNombresUsuario();
            var esta = false;

            foreach (string elem in listaUsuarios)
            {
                if (txtBuscar.Text == elem)
                {
                    esta = true;
                }
            }

            if (txtBuscar.Text == "")
            {
                //Si intentas buscar con el campo vacio no haces nada
            }
            else if (esta) //Si el nombre de usuario suministrado por el txtbox existe en la base de datos, procedes
            {   //Si es el enter hace la busqueda
                var perfilUsuario = new PerfilUsuario(txtBuscar.Text, caller);
                perfilUsuario.Show();
            }
        }

        private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using( var pEspera = new PantallaEspera(EjecutarBusqueda))
            {
                pEspera.ShowDialog(this);
            }
            Hide();
        }
```

Why is it crashing? This is my first year studying C#, so maybe I have done something wrong. This is what happens to the second form: [image]

And this is how it looks without the Action: [image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's safe to use continuewith to close a form; would that cause a thread other than the thread that created a windows control, to access that control? That's a big nono- windows forms controls must always only be accessed by the thread that created them. I'd await the task and close the form normally on the UI thread

Comment: Thing is it works fine on another program with Forms I made, and I copied the exact same code. And when I try your solution, an error appears saying "The operator await can only be used inside an async method." Any idea?

Comment: See the edit to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    //avoid handling events this way; attach an event handler instead unless you specifically EE's to override the base onload 
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Task.Run(Proceso).Wait();
        this.Close();
    }
```